# Redirecting conditionally based on radio button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I would like to know if there is a way in HTML5 to take a user to a particular page based on what the user chooses for a radio button selection using HTML5.

For example if the user chooses the "male" radio button and hits submit, then I want to take him to `.../male.html` or if female is chosen and then submit is clicked then take her to `.../female.html`

If its not possible to do this in HTML5, I could figure something out in javascript despite my lack of experience with that language. However, I don't know how I would implement the code to only run when submit is pressed, could you give me a little guidance?

As a sidenote, I don't wish to use any jQuery or other libraries. I want it to be either HTML5 if possible, or plain javascript.

Comment: If you want to do it purely using  html5 then you need two submit buttons for corresponding radio buttons.But that doesn't make any sense..That is the way you do it only using html5.

Answer (score 1):

HTML(5):

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-male" value="Male" />
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-female" value="Female" />
</form>
```

JS(5):

```
var submit = function (e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (document.getElementById('gender-male').checked) {
        window.location = 'male.html';
    } else if (document.getElementById('gender-female').checked) {
        window.location = 'female.html';
    }

    return false;
};

window.onload = function () {
    var form = document.getElementById('form');

    if (form.attachEvent) {
        form.attachEvent('submit', submit);
    } else {
        form.addEventListener('submit', submit);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing HTML 5 in your posted HTML; and I'm not sure that your JavaScript has any requirement for the 5 either (since it doesn't appear to require ECMAscript 5).

Comment: He asked for HTML5 so I just gave him what he asked for!

Comment: My point is that it's *not* strictly HTML 5 (unless the appropriate doctype is used); nor is HTML 5 *required*.

Answer (score 0):

Have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate how it could be done with HTML and Javascript. There's no way to do it with just HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/benwong/W4FVC/

HTML

```
<input id="MaleRadio" type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked="checked">male</input>
<input id="FemaleRadio" type="radio" name="sex" value="female">female</input>
<input id="SubmitButton" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Javascript

```
var maleRadio = document.getElementById("MaleRadio"),
    femaleRadio = document.getElementById("FemaleRadio"),
    submitButton = document.getElementById("SubmitButton");

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (maleRadio.checked) {
        alert('male');
        window.location = "male.html";
    } else {
        alert('female');
        window.location = "female.html";
    }
}, false);
```